# About connecting web database with Android application

Tags: android, json

I am currently writing an android application which needs a web database for storing the data. I have used Visual Studio 2010 to create a webpage act as a web service , but the question is how can I change the data to Json and let the android application to read it?
I am just a beginner for writing the apps, anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to return JSON String from your web service. From the Android Application end, you need to read those JSON String. For reading JSON Parsing visit [this](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) link. you can also visit following link.

More generally: http://www.google.com/search?q=android+json+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html
 I have visited this link and follow his procedure , and the output is "Hello World, ParselJon" , does it mean that it is successful?

Comment: I have faced a problem after converting the C# to Json but I face the following problems
"a circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type" I have tried to put [ScriptIgnore] in front of some code that I think is the problem, but the problem still presist